# Query with triple selector

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5, lambda

I'm currently have  Lambda Expresion: http://pastebin.com/ZGCiQdHe

And i get ArgumentException in 53 line 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340145(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340145%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
var lExpresion = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, parametrsNumber, parametrsTyp, parametrsLp);
```

But i not understand what i do wrong.

I want to get:

```
    WHERE ((twr_gidnumer =1 and twr_gidtyp = 1 and twr_gidlp = 1) OR 
    (twr_gidnumer =1 and twr_gidtyp = 1 and twr_gidlp = 2))
```

--ANSWERR FULL

Based on article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/31/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-ii.aspx
[https://stackoverflow.com/Converting 2 argument Lambda expression to 1 argument Lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3530666/266202)

```
public static Expression<Func<CDNXL_TwrKarty, bool>> Bind2nd(Expression<Func<CDNXL_TwrKarty, CDNXL_TwrKarty,CDNXL_TwrKarty, bool>> source)
{
    Expression newBody = new Rewriter(source.Parameters[0]).Visit(source.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<CDNXL_TwrKarty, bool>>(newBody, source.Parameters[0]);
}

internal class Rewriter : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression candidate_;

    public Rewriter(ParameterExpression candidate)
    {
        candidate_ = candidate;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
    {
        return candidate_;
    }
}
```

```
//REPLACE EXECUTING PLACE
var retMultiLamnda = Expression.Lambda<Func<CDNXL_TwrKarty, CDNXL_TwrKarty, CDNXL_TwrKarty, bool>>(body, parametrsNumber, parametrsTyp, parametrsLp);
var retOneLambda = Bind2nd(retMultiLamnda);
var retQuery = query.Where(retOneLambda);
return retQuery;
```

**Thanx [Rafal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1495595/rafal) for Help.**

Comment: +1 for ExprssionVisitor nice to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that I see is that your delegate type does not math with your invocation list. You expect to create function that receives one argument of type `TEntity` and yet you pass tree parameter expressions to function. Note that you execute this overload of [Lablda method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336566(v=vs.90).aspx).

OK, I'll try to be more clear:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<Arg1Type,...,ArgNType,ReturnType>>
    (body,parameterExpressionForArg1,...,parameterExpressionForArgN);
```

Those generic arguments `ArgType` must match with `parameterExpressionsForArg`. There must be equal number of generic types for argumetnts as parameterExpressions for arguments. And types of those must also match.

So if you want to have tree `parameterExpressions` for some reason then you have to have tree arguments in your method:

```
 Expression.Lambda<Func<CDNXL_TwrKarty,CDNXL_TwrKarty,CDNXL_TwrKarty, bool>>(body, parametrsNumber, parametrsTyp, parametrsLp);
```

might be correct call in this case obviously it wont match the `Where` call.

If you want to merge tree expressions into one matching `Where` argument then you have to replace all redundant `ParamteterExpressions`.

Comment: I remove TEntity and write for one class http://pastebin.com/92PetJLK. Result the same.

Comment: But, How reduce to one parameter?

Comment: You need to traverse those expression trees and crate your own. Study [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573517/generic-method-to-calcuate-euclidean-distance-using-expressions/11574571#11574571) where this topic is covered by me and Iridium. The complexity of this task will depend on expressions that are passed to your function.